# Explication java code for a beginner

Tags: java, timer, schedule

I am a beginner java programmer and i saw a code on internet about my projet.
But i didn't understand what it does ? Anyone can explain ?
What are 1000s ?

```
private Timer timer = null;
private int timeWorking;

private void xxxxxxxxxxx() {

    if (timer == null) {

        timer = new Timer("Time");
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                timeWorking++;

            }

        }, 1000, 1000);

    }

}
```

Comment: Milliseconds, or one second.  It's scheduling a call back (to the `TimerTask`) every second, with a second delay.  Take a look at the [JavaDocs for `Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) for more details

Comment: check the api for the Timer class.

Comment: ... located at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule-java.util.TimerTask-long-long-

Comment: @gustafc Breaking News: Java 8 is out! https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule-java.util.TimerTask-long-long-

Answer (score 0):

This is a call to [`java.util.Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule-java.util.TimerTask-long-long-):

> Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-delay execution, beginning after the specified delay.

Both `delay` and `period` are in milliseconds. 1000 milliseconds are equal to one second.

Answer (score 0):

The see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)) of Timer.schedule()

```
task - task to be scheduled.delay - 
delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed.period - 
time in milliseconds between successive task executions.
```

Answer (score 0):

See [java.util.Timer documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

The first "1000" means *delay* - delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed.
The second "1000" means *period* - time in milliseconds between successive task executions.

Answer (score 0):

public void schedule(TimerTask task,  long delay,  long period) you are calling this method with delay 1000ms and period 1000ms.